# Invalid operation: column "[column_name]" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;

Tags: mysql, postgresql, group-by, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I have read almost 10+ questions related to mine but no one worked in my case. As i have 3 tables in my DB and i am trying to calculate sale from them with respect to time (Yearly sale). where i need to `GROUP BY` my query by `date_added`. In `MYSQL` it worked fine and give me fine result but in redshift i am stuck.

**MYSQL QUERY**:

```
SELECT
MONTHNAME(o.date_added) AS MONTH,
YEAR(o.date_added) AS YEAR,
COUNT(o.order_id) AS orders,
FROM
order o
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT
    op.order_id,
    SUM(op.quantity) AS op_qty,
    SUM(op.total) AS total,
    SUM(op.cost) AS cost
FROM
    order_product op
GROUP BY
    op.order_id
) op
ON
op.order_id = o.order_id
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT
    order_id,
    SUM(IF(CODE = 'coupon', VALUE, 0)) AS coupon
FROM
    order_total
WHERE
    1
GROUP BY
    order_id
) ot
ON
ot.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE
(
    DATE(o.date_added) >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 24 MONTH) AND DATE(o.date_added) <= 
DATE(NOW())) AND(o.order_status_id = '22' OR o.order_status_id = '23')
GROUP BY
    MONTH(o.date_added),
    YEAR(o.date_added)
ORDER BY
    date_added ASC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

This MYSQL query working very fine but when i convert it to RedShift's POSTGRE format it gives me error of `Invalid operation: column "o.date_added" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;`

**POSTGRES Query**:

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.date_added) AS month,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.date_added) AS year,
COUNT(o.order_id) AS orders
FROM
orders o  
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        op.order_id,
        SUM(op.quantity) AS op_qty,
        SUM(op.total) AS total,
        SUM(op.cost) AS cost            
    FROM
        order_product op 
    GROUP BY
        op.order_id
) op 
    ON op.order_id = o.order_id             
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        order_id,
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN CODE = 'coupon' THEN VALUE 
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS coupon                      
    FROM
        order_total 
    WHERE
        1 
    GROUP BY
        order_id
) ot 
ON ot.order_id = o.order_id                        
WHERE
(
    DATE(o.date_added) >= now() + interval '-24 month' 
    AND DATE(o.date_added) <= DATE(NOW())
)                               
AND (
    o.order_status_id = '22' 
    OR o.order_status_id = '23'
)                               
GROUP BY
(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.date_added), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.date_added))
ORDER BY
o.date_added ASC LIMIT 25
```

Is there any syntax error in postgre query and also why i need to add `o.date_added` in `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the ERROR.I used SQL Workbench and get the Error about `NOW()` function that i was using in my `POSTGRE` query.

Simply, i juts replaced `NOW()` with `CURRENT_DATE` and things worked for me. Also, i get Error for `LIMIT 0, 25` but in POSTGRE , they allow `LIMIT 25 [OFFSET n]` .

Now my query looks like:

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.date_added) AS month,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.date_added) AS year,
COUNT(o.order_id) AS orders
FROM
orders o  
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        op.order_id,
        SUM(op.quantity) AS op_qty,
        SUM(op.total) AS total,
        SUM(op.cost) AS cost            
    FROM
        order_product op 
    GROUP BY
        op.order_id
) op 
    ON op.order_id = o.order_id             
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        order_id                       
    FROM
        order_total 
    WHERE
        1 
    GROUP BY
        order_id
) ot 
    ON ot.order_id = o.order_id                        
WHERE
(
    DATE(o.date_added) >= CURRENT_DATE + interval '-24 month' 
    AND DATE(o.date_added) <= DATE(CURRENT_DATE)
)                              
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.date_added), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.date_added)
ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC LIMIT 25
```

**NOTE: IF YOU ARE WORKING ON REDSHIFT. IT DO NOT BERIEF ABOUT ERROR. I RECOMMEND TO USE SQL WORKBENCH. IT EXPLAIN ABOUT ERROR.**

Answer (score 1):

Your `ORDER BY` clause has `o.date_added` in it but your actual result set does not have it. The `ORDER BY` is done after the query is done.

You can use:

```
ORDER BY month asc, year asc LIMIT 25
```

Also, you can remove the extra parentheses from the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.date_added), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.date_added)
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wNrnmASK89H83FAh3poiGi/3)

See Redshift [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions_leader_node_only.html) for use of `now()` function. Use `getdate()` instead, as the `now()` seems to be [deprecated](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html#date-functions-summary).

Comment: it gives error ` Invalid operation: could not identify an ordering operator for type record;`

Comment: Are you passing the order by columns as variable? See DB-Fiddle. Also, you did not mention which version of PostgreSQL you are using.

Comment: sir postgree versionis 8.0.2 (I am using in AWS Redshift).

Comment: Could be another error triggered by Redshift´s PostgreSQL version. Try removing the extra parentheses from the `GROUP BY`. See DB-Fiddle.

Comment: thanks for being with me... i have copied your query ..match everything but still getting new error.. `Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;`

Comment: OK, that is an different error and points to how Redshift allows function usage only on leader node. The main suspect in your query would be the `now()` function. See documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

A column in an `ORDER BY` clause in a query containing `GROUP BY` works as if it were mentioned in the `SELECT` clause.

You have

```
SELECT
MONTHNAME(o.date_added) AS MONTH,
YEAR(o.date_added) AS YEAR,
COUNT(o.order_id) AS orders,
FROM
order o 
...
GROUP BY
    MONTH(o.date_added),
    YEAR(o.date_added)
ORDER BY
    date_added ASC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

In MySQL this takes advantage of its notorious nonstandard handling of `GROUP BY` (read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

What you want, to get a query that works in multiple DBMSs, is this instead.

```
ORDER BY
    MONTH(o.date_added) ASC,
    YEAR(o.date_added) ASC
```

Adding `o.date_added` to your `GROUP BY` clause is incorrect, because you are grouping not by the entire date, but by the month and year of the date.

Comment: sir it is giving an error `Invalid operation: could not identify an ordering operator for type record;`